# Fluentd source path to tail remote files

Tags: plugins, tail, fluentd

all, I'm new to this site, and Linux. I've just installed fluentd on Linux Mint. I want to use it to tale .evl logs at remote sites (by ip address) on our network, and send an email when a certain phrase appears. I'm reading on how to set up the tail input plugin. However, in the source section of fluent.conf, how do I specify the path for a remote file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) as of Aug 2015, doesn't support tailing the remote files (@see [in_tail](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail) plugin). You probably need to copy the files from remote to local via scp or rsync. Or you can post the data remotely via http (@see [in_http](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_http) plugin)